# Possible to capture URL (being loaded) on Child Browser?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

**Hi,**

The situation is like this.

My project requires to use PhoneGap for building web application on iOS and Android.

90% of the pages are embedded on device. 10% are on remote site that should be loaded with Child Browser.

But is it possible to capture any URL or loading on ChildBrowser, so that my application can pre-process some actions before another page is loaded ?

Thanks,

Best regards,
**Henry Fok**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The ChildBrowser onLocationChange method allows you to intercept the URL and do your own thing.

See the docs at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ChildBrowser.

We have an example of onLocationChange in our Barcode Tutorial [here](http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3p2).